# how to remove children data in case many to many relationship in laravel by using observer?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

there is a (card model) bleongsToMany contacts, and there is a (contact model) is bleongsToMany cards, I want when (card) get updated his children in the middle table in the relation became removed.

I'm trying to do this by using (the observer), I did all steps correctly but **the issue is**:

- when (card model) updated his children still exist in the middle table of the relationship, I want to remove them when any update on the card.

**Route:**

```
    Route::get('/test',function(){
         $card = \App\Models\Card::find(1);

    $card->  update([
            'name' => 'firstCard1',
            'user_name' =>1,
        ]);
    return true;
});
```

**Observer:**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Observers;

use App\Models\Card;

class CardObserver
{
    public function updated(Card $card)
    {
        $card -> contact()-> delete();
    }


}
```

**Card Model:**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Observers\CardObserver;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Card extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'user_id ',
    ];

    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $hidden = ['pivot'];


    public function contact()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Contact::class, 'card_contacts', 'card_id');
    }

    public function connection()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Connection::class, '');
    }

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        Card::observe(CardObserver::class);
    }

}
```

**Contact Model:**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Contact extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'provider_id',
        'user_id',
        'contact_string'
    ];

    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $hidden = ['pivot'];


    public function card(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Card::class,'card_contacts','contact_id');
    }

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id');
    }

    public function provider(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Provider::class,'provider_id');
    }
}
```

**Card_contact Model (the pivot table):**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CardContact extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'card_id',
        'contact_id',
    ];
    public $timestamps = true;
}
```

any help please?

Comment: For Many-to-Many relationships, the method you're looking for is `detach`.  `$card->contact()->detach();` will detach all contacts from `$card`. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#attaching-detaching

Comment: Thaaanks it works